# How to prevent MaterialDialog freezing

Tags: android, download, bitmap, android-glide

I'm trying to download a picture using Glide, and set it as wallpaper, and while it downloads, it shows a dialog using MaterialDialogs library, but somehow when the picture is almost loaded, the dialog freezes for a second ... this is my code:

```
final MaterialDialog downloadDialogA = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                                .content(R.string.downloading_wallpaper)
                                .progress(true, 0)
                                .cancelable(false)
                                .show();

                        Glide.with(context)
                                .load(wallurl)
                                .asBitmap()
                                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                                        downloadDialogA.setContent(context.getString(R.string.setting_wall_title));
                                        if (resource != null) {
                                            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                                            try {
                                                wm.setBitmap(resource);
                                                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.set_as_wall_done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                Log.v("Wall", "It worked!");
                                            } catch (IOException e2) {
                                                Toast.makeText(context, e2.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                Log.v("Wall", "Error " + e2.getMessage());
                                            }
                                        }
                                        downloadDialogA.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
```

Please note that I don't want to use other library to download the picture. It works fine. I just want to prevent the dialog from freezing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it.

I created a new AsyncTask which code is:

```
public class ApplyWallpaper extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private MaterialDialog dialog;
    private Bitmap resource;

    public ApplyWallpaper(Context context, MaterialDialog dialog, Bitmap resource) {
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
        this.context = context;
        this.dialog = dialog;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
        Boolean worked;
        try {
            wm.setBitmap(resource);
            worked = true;
            Log.e("Wall", "It worked!");
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            worked = false;
            Log.e("Wall", "Error " + e2.getMessage());
        }
        return worked;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean worked) {
        if (worked){
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.set_as_wall_done, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when the resource was ready (using the callback method provided by Glide), I executed the AsyncTask, like this:

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(wallurl)
        .asBitmap()
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                if (resource != null) {
                    downloadDialogA.setContent(context.getString(R.string.setting_wall_title));
                    new ApplyWallpaper(context, downloadDialogA, resource).execute();
                }
            }
        });
```

And worked flawlessly.

Thanks to [Javier Santos](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+JavierSantos/about) for the guidance.